# Do we have provision for interceptor chaining in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-security, interceptor

Let's say we have two interceptors "LogInterceptor" and "AuthInterceptor".
The first interceptor logs the incoming request and the second one authenticate it.
    Aim: Chain LogIntercptor and AuthInterceptor. First I want the logInterceptor be called and after that AuthInterceptor should be executed.
    Note: I know about "redirect" and returning false (Please don't suggest the one)

```
---------------------Log Interceptor---------------------------------------







    //First Inteceptor

    @Component
    public class LogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
    {
        private final Logger Logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

            //take action base on incoming IP
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            request.setAttribute("startTime",startTime); 
            if(request.getRemoteAddr().startsWith("192")) 
                 {
                response.sendRedirect("/auth-failed"); //redirect to default
                return false;
            }
            return  true;

        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable ModelAndView 
         modelAndView) throws Exception
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable Exception 
        ex) throws Exception
        {



        }
      }
```

//Second interceptor  "Code is however not complete, I am just seeeking how this can be achieved."
        class AuthInterceptor
        {

```
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure the `Interceptor` are added in your desired orders when configuring `InterceptorRegistry`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private LogInterceptor logInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private AuthInterceptor authInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(logInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(authInterceptor);
    }

}
```

In case you have multiple `WebMvcConfigurer` , you can simply use `@Order` to control which the execution order of `WebMvcConfigurer` (lower value has higher priority):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class FooWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

}

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class BarWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

}
```